# take variable in constructor of class und modifying python

Tags: python, class, oop, constructor

How can access the value of a variable that lies within the class constructor?

code is

```
class Rectangle:
    count = 0

    def __init__(self,width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height


        bla = 10
        Rectangle.count += 1

        default_area = 20

    def calcArea(self):
        area = self.width * self.height
        return area

    def getcount(self):
        print(self.count)
```

I want to modify `default_area`; how can I do this?

Comment: So as written, it is a local variable and gone so you cannot access it.  You could promote it to an instance or a class variable and then you can access it.  (Google it.)  However, while Python allows this, it isn't very good OOD . . . allowed by the language, but I would complain about it if we did a code review together . . . I would expect you to have a good justification for it and probably ask you to promote it to the interface with full get/set support.

Comment: How do you intend to use the variable?  Will there be only one for the class, or will each instance have its own `default_area`?  If it's a default, why do you want to change it?

Comment: Prune - I have seen this kind of thing for testing.  In default/production it does X, but for testing it does Y; maybe accesses a mock instead of a server.  Makes my skin crawl though . . . just a bug waiting to happen when it gets abused in production later by some other team member three years later.

Answer (score 0):

You may associate your variable with the class by writing:
`self.default_area = 20`. Then you can access it by `self.default_area`. The variables `bla`, `default_area` are defined in the local function scope of the class-constructor and are garbage collected due to them having no references any more. When a variable has no reference it can't be accessed. The variable area in CalcArea and the result can directly be returned.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.Width = width
        self.Height = height

        self.default_area = self.CalcArea()

    def CalcArea(self):
        return self.Width * self.Height

    def GetInfo(self):
        print("X:", self.Width)
        print("Y:", self.Height)
        print("Area:", self.default_area)

rect1 = Rectangle(10, 20)
rect1.GetInfo()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all instances to share the same `default_area`, lift it to be a class attribute:

```
class Rectangle:
    count = 0
    default_area = 20

# Modify
Rectangle.default_area = 30
```

If you want each instance to have its own, make it a class attribute (as described by previous postings):

```
def __init__(self,width, height):
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.default_area = 20

# Modify
rect1.default_area = 30
```

If you want this to be a true default value, make it so in the constructor:

```
def __init__(self,width, height, area=20):
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.area = area

# Modify
rect1.area = 30
```